Exercise on Cauchy problem
I am trying to study the following Cauchy problem:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
&y'=(1+\arctan(ty))\cos(y)(1+\sin(y)) \\
&y(0)=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
I found that the solution $y^*$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and $y^*(t)\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $\cos(y^*)$, $1+\sin(y^*)>0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and the sign of the derivative is then determined by $1+\arctan(ty^*(t))$, which is equal to 0 if and only if
\begin{equation*}
y^*(t)=-\frac{\tan(1)}{t}
\end{equation*}
It follows that $y^{*'}(t)>0$ if and only if
\begin{equation*}
y^*(t)>-\frac{\tan(1)}{t}
\end{equation*}
and $y^{*'}(t)<0$ if and only if
\begin{equation*}
y^*(t)<-\frac{\tan(1)}{t}
\end{equation*}
However, I do not know anything about the solution $y^*$, so how can I study the sign of its derivative?
Thanks in advance for any answer and help!

That's not a solution. Inserting  $$y=-\tan(1)/t,  y' = \tan(1)/t^2 $$  yields $$\tan(1)/t^2 =0$$

I did not say that it is a solution

There is something you know about the solution: $y^*(0)=0.$
